# Adding elements to cyclic Single Linked Lists

Tags: java

I am trying to add an element to the end of a cyclic Single Linked List for my homework
assignment. But for some reason I am having a lot of problems.

I have a `_tail` pointer, and `_dummy`. The add method in JUnit test says that when checking the add method it returns null instead of 1. (1 being what was added to list)

Here is my code

```
 private static class Node<T>{
    Node<T> next;
    T data;
    public Node(T data, Node<T> next){
        this.next = next;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

private Node<T> _tail;
private int _count;
private int _version;
private Node<T> _dummy;  

 public CyclicLinkedList(){
    _dummy = new Node<T>(null, null);
    _dummy.next = _dummy;
    _tail = _dummy;
    _count = 0;
    assert _wellFormed();
}
```

and here is my add method

```
@Override
public boolean add(T x){
    assert _wellFormed();

    Node<T> n = new Node<T>(x, _tail.next);
    _tail.next = n;
    _tail = n;

    ++_version;
    ++_count;

    assert _wellFormed();
    return true;
}
```

The assertWellformed states that the linked list is wrongly cyclic. The _wellFormed() method has already been implemented by the class instructor so that is not the problem. Need some pointers! Thanks. Here is the test to see if the test is wrongly cyclic.

```
 // check for cycles:
    Node<T> fast = _tail.next;
    for (Node<T> p = _tail; fast != null && fast.next != null && fast != _tail       && fast.next != _tail; p = p.next) {
        if (p == fast) return _report("list is wrongly cyclic");
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }
```

Comment: @dermike Please stop adding the homework tag. It is obsolete and in the process of being removed. Check the tag wiki for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
_tail.next = n;
    _tail = n;
```

You should add one more line at the start of that code in add method:-

```
n.next = _tail.next;
```

So, your code becomes: -

```
n.next = _tail.next;
_tail.next = n;
_tail = n;
```

You need to make your new node point to the first node, to make it cyclic.

And since, `_tail.next` I assume must be pointing to the first element, before adding a new node to the `List`, so assign `_tail.next` to `n.next` before adding it to the list to make `n` also now point to the first `node`.

So, at the first line, both your nodes: - `n` node and `_tail` node, point to the first node. Now, detach your `_tail` node from first node, and make it point to the `n` node. And at last, make your `n` node as `_tail` node.

Comment: Well _tail = _dummy and _dummy.next = _dummy at the start. and I have to add an element to the end so that the element.next = _dummy. and _dummy.next = the added element and then set _tail to the element at the end. I tried your code and it still did not work.

Comment: You should do: - `element.next = _dummy.next` as your first line. Because its `dummy.next` that points to the `first node`.

Comment: `element.next = _dummy.next`. and `_dummy.next = the added element` and then `set _tail to the element at the end`

Comment: but what if its empty and there is no first node. just _dummy is in the list

Comment: @Milwaukoholic. Ok, now what exactly is your `_dummy`? Can you post the constructor of your `Node` class?

Comment: @Milwaukoholic. I'm assuming that `_dummy` is your first node.

Comment: i posted the Node constructor. _dummy gets setup in the CyclicLinkedList constructor

Comment: @Milwaukoholic. Well, seems like your code should work perfectly fine. What I told you to do, you are doing it in constructor. What problem is it giving?

Comment: It says the list is wrongly cyclic. And that after the test using the add method, when it checks the added element it says it returns null instead of what is supposed to be added. Let me post the cyclic wellformed test aswell

Comment: @Milwaukoholic. Well, its hard for me to understand that loop. I am getting lost there. I am afraid I can't help you from here. Sorry for that. May be someone can come up, and see what's wrong. :(

Comment: @Milwaukoholic. May be I would add a Bounty for this question for you, when it gets old enough to get a bounty (its 2 days probably), and it doesn't gets answered till then.